# Response.End terminating page events within a sharepoint page

Tags: c#, asp.net, sharepoint

[article](http://www.french-industries.com/post/2010/04/09/ResponseEnd-terminating-page-events-within-a-sharepoint-page.aspx)

This article explains how to fix a bug in Sharepoint where the page would go dead after a save dialog is prompted. It states to add in my case where the link button is under the page where the link button resides

```
exportButton.OnClientClick = "document.getElementsByTagName(\'form\')[0].onsubmit = function() {return true;}";
```

Ive tried this the error it produces is "server tag not well formed". My form name is aspnetForm and my link button name is TestLinkButton. Any ideas what im doing wrong from the article?

Answer (score 0):

I'm curious what this is really solving, but I'll put that curiosity aside for now and just answer your question.

Get rid of those backslashes:

```
   document.getElementsByTagName('form')[0].onsubmit = function() {return true;};
```

If that doesn't work, can you explain how you are injecting this line into the page? Maybe I can help out more then.